# Deploying Laravel 5.7 to Google App Engine

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine

After deploying Laravel 5.7.0 to Google App Engine, got this error when visiting through `gcloud app browse`.

`Class 'BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider' not found in Application.php line 636`

Tested on local machine successfully.

.env file: https://pastebin.com/etqGM4Pd

app.yaml:

`runtime: php72
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1`

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @JigneshJoisar did nothing, app engine doesn't use my vendor directory (according to .gcloudignore file)

Comment: Tried with empty Laravel 5.7 project, same result

Comment: deploy with APP_DEBUG=true. lets see whats happening

Comment: @barghouthi it's already enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer already on Google Cloud repo:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/736

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar difficulty trying to deploy my application on App engine. I will share with you how I fixed it.

- remove routes from api.php (I didn't need these for my application)
- enable cloud SQL api [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https:%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.164522367.-1360075521.1510572080)
- Follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)  **follow next two steps before deploying**
- make the following changes to the composer.json file. The tutorial is incorrect.
  ```
  "post-install-cmd": [
              "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
              "php artisan optimize",
              "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
          ]
  ```
- Configure your app.yaml file like so:
  ```
  runtime: php
  env: flex

  runtime_config:
    document_root: public

  env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_LOG: errorlog
    APP_KEY: APP_KEY (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_HOST: localhost
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_DATABASE: DATABASE_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_USERNAME: USERNAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)

    QUEUE_DRIVER: database

  beta_settings:
      # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
      # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
      cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
  ```